# Group elements and drag group with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm using [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) in jQuery UI to create a Solitaire card game. If a dragged card has other cards over it and all these cards are in a descending straight flush (like 5 of clubs in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRbwu.jpg)), all these cards should be dragged at once and appended to the card the they are dropped onto.

I've tried to solve this by adding some code the *start* event of `draggable();`:

```
var thisAndAllNextCards = $(this).nextAll().addBack();

if (thisAndAllNextCards.length > 1) {
  $(thisAndAllNextCards).each(function(){
    if ($(this).data("value") == $(this).next('.card').data("value") +1 $(this).data("value") == $(this).next('.card').data("value") +1 && $(this).data("suit") == $(this).next('.card').data("suit")) {

      $(this).nextAll().addBack().wrapAll( "<div class='cardGroup'/>");

      /* All the cards in the variable thisAndAllNextCards (i.e. all the cards in the div with class 'cardGroup')
         should be dragged as a group and appended to the card they are dropped onto */

    }
  });
}
```

The code checks wether the cards are in a descending straight flush and, if so, wraps them in a temporary div. Then I'm stuck. The positioning of the cards gets messed up and I don't know how to drag the wrapping div instead of the clicked card. I don't even know if my idea of wrapping the cards in a new div is good.

**My question:**
How do I select the cards in the flush, keep them in place (visually and in DOM) while dragging them and then append them to the card they are dropped onto?

Click *Show code snippet* below to see the code in it's entirety.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var column1 = [];
    var column2 = [];
    var column3 = [];
    var column4 = [];
    var column5 = [];
    var column6 = [];
    var column7 = [];
    var column8 = [];
    var column9 = [];
    var column10 = [];
    
    var decksAmount = 2;
    var suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts"];
    var values = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"];
    var unshuffledDeck;
    var shuffledDeck;
    
    init();
    appendCardsToColumns();

    function init() {

        unshuffledDeck = getUnshuffledDeck();
    
        shuffledDeck = shuffleDeck(unshuffledDeck);

        divideCardsInColumns(shuffledDeck);

    }

    function getUnshuffledDeck() {
        
        var deck = new Array();

        var id = 1;
        
        for (var y = 0; y < decksAmount; y++ ) {
            for(var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
                for(var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
                    var card = {value: values[x], suit: suits[i], status: 'hidden', class: 'card', id: id, 'status': 'hidden'};
                    id++
                    deck.push(card);
                }
            }
        }

        return deck;
    }
    
        
    function shuffleDeck(array) {
        
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }

        return array;
      
    }

    function divideCardsInColumns(cards) {


        $(cards).slice(0, 6).each(function(index) {
            column1.push(this);
        });

        $(cards).slice(6, 12).each(function(index) {
            column2.push(this);
        });

        $(cards).slice(12, 18).each(function(index) {
            column3.push(this);
        });

        $(cards).slice(18, 24).each(function(index) {
            column4.push(this);
        });

        $(cards).slice(24, 29).each(function(index) {
            column5.push(this);
        });

        $(cards).slice(29, 34).each(function(index) {
            column6.push(this);
        });

        $(cards).slice(34, 39).each(function(index) {
            column7.push(this);
        });

        $(cards).slice(39, 44).each(function(index) {
            column8.push(this);
        });

        $(cards).slice(44, 49).each(function(index) {
            column9.push(this);
        });

        $(cards).slice(49, 54).each(function(index) {
            column10.push(this);
        });

    }

    function appendCardsToColumns() {

        var columns = [];

        columns.push(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5,column6, column7, column8, column9, column10);

        $(columns).each(function(index) {

            var column = $(".column")[index];

            var numberOfCardsInColumn = this.length;

            $(this).each(function(index) {

                $('<div id="' + this.id + '" class="' + this.class + '" data-value="' + this.value + '" data-suit="' + this.suit + '" data-status="' + this.status + '">' + this.value + " of " + this.suit + '<div/>').appendTo(column);

                // Get last card in column
                var lastCard = index == numberOfCardsInColumn -1;

                // Make last card in column draggable and open after it has been appended
                if (lastCard) {
                    $("#" + this.id).attr("data-status","open");
                    $("#" + this.id).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
                }

            });

        });

        initializeDragAndDrop();

        function initializeDragAndDrop() {

            // Make open cards droppable and only accept a cards with a value one less than itself
            $(".card[data-status='open']").droppable({     

                accept: function(d) {

                    if ($(d[0]).data("value") == $(this).data("value") -1) {

                        return true;

                    }

                }

            });

            $( ".card[data-status='open']" ).draggable({

                start: function( event, ui ) {

                    var allZIindex = [];
                    
                    $('.card').each(function(){

                        if ($(this)[0].style.zIndex == null) {
                            $(this)[0].style.zIndex = 1;
                        }

                        allZIindex.push($(this)[0].style.zIndex);

                    });

                    var highestZIndex = Math.max.apply(Math, allZIindex);

                    $(this)[0].style.zIndex = highestZIndex + 1;

                    var thisAndAllNextCards = $(this).nextAll().addBack();

                    if (thisAndAllNextCards.length > 1) {
                        $(thisAndAllNextCards).each(function(){
                            if ($(this).data("value") == $(this).next('.card').data("value") +1 && $(this).data("suit") == $(this).next('.card').data("suit")) {

                              $(this).nextAll().addBack().wrapAll( "<div class='cardGroup'/>");

                                // All the cards in the variable thisAndAllNextCards (i.e. all the cards in div with class 'cardGroup') should be dragged as a group and appended to the droppable when dropped

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    
                }

            });

        }

        $( ".card" ).on( "drop", function( event, ui ) {

            $(ui.draggable).prev().attr("data-status","open");

            $(ui.draggable).prev().draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });

            $(ui.draggable).insertAfter('#' + $(this).attr("id"));

            $(ui.draggable).css('top', '').css('left', '');

            initializeDragAndDrop();

        } );

    }


});
```

```css
.some-page-wrapper {
    margin: 15px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.column {
    /*border: 1px solid;*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}


.card[data-status='hidden'] {
    background-color: DarkGray;
    color: DarkGray;
}

.card {
  background-color: LightGray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  font-size: 1vw;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: calc(8vw * 1.4);
  width: 8vw;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10vw;
}

.column .card:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spindelharpan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class='some-page-wrapper'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='column' id='column1'></div>
        <div class='column' id='column2'></div>
        <div class='column' id='column3'></div>
        <div class='column' id='column4'></div>
        <div class='column' id='column5'></div>
        <div class='column' id='column6'></div>
        <div class='column' id='column7'></div>
        <div class='column' id='column8'></div>
        <div class='column' id='column9'></div>
        <div class='column' id='column10'></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest a Face Up and Face Down type of container. This way the User can drag the Face Up container, with all the cards in it, to another stack.

Comment: Thank you @Twisty! A Face Up/Face Down container wouldn't work as not all cards with the face up should be dragged as a group. Only if **all** the cards after a face up card are in a **descending straight flush** (like in the image I attached as an example), should these cards be in a container. That part I've got covered. The problem I have is to get such a "invisible" container to be dragged when I drag the first card in the container.

Comment: @Twisty. To clarify: I can make the container draggable I have it draggable by the first card in the cointainer. This is done with the _handle_ option of draggable: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle. However, since the cards themselves are draggable, the first card in the container gets dragged alone. The first card is the handle of two draggables; itself and it's container.

Comment: @Twisty I solved that particular problem now by disabling the draggable functionality of the first card when I create the container. Now it only works as a handle.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {

  function lastDownClick(c) {
    var lastCard = $(".down .card:last", c);
    lastCard.click(function() {
      makeUpDeck(c);
    });
  }

  function makeUpDeck(c) {
    var lastCard = $(".down .card:last", c).detach();
    var up = $("<div>", {
        class: "up"
      })
      .draggable({
        handle: "div.card:first",
        revert: "invalid",
        zIndex: 1000
      })
      .droppable({
        accept: function(d) {
          var lastCard = $(".card:last", this);
          if (d.hasClass("card")) {
            if (d.data("value") == (lastCard.data("value") - 1)) {
              return true;
            }
          } else {
            if ($(".card:eq(0)", d).data("value") == (lastCard.data("value") - 1)) {
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        },
        drop: function(e, ui) {
          var cards;
          if (ui.draggable.hasClass("card")) {
            cards = ui.draggable.css({
              top: "",
              left: ""
            });
          } else {
            cards = ui.draggable.children().detach();
          }
          $(this).append(cards);
          if (!ui.draggable.hasClass("card")) {
            ui.draggable.remove();
          }
          if ($(this).children().length >= 2) {
            singleDrag($(".card:last", this));
          }
        }
      })
    lastCard.attr("data-status", "open").appendTo(up);
    up.appendTo(c);
    lastDownClick(c);
  }

  function singleDrag(card) {
    card.draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      zIndex: 1000
    });
  }

  var column1 = [];
  var column2 = [];
  var column3 = [];
  var column4 = [];
  var column5 = [];
  var column6 = [];
  var column7 = [];
  var column8 = [];
  var column9 = [];
  var column10 = [];

  var decksAmount = 2;
  var suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts"];
  var values = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"];
  var unshuffledDeck;
  var shuffledDeck;

  init();
  appendCardsToColumns();

  function init() {
    unshuffledDeck = getUnshuffledDeck();
    shuffledDeck = shuffleDeck(unshuffledDeck);
    divideCardsInColumns(shuffledDeck);
  }

  function getUnshuffledDeck() {
    var deck = new Array();
    var id = 1;
    for (var y = 0; y < decksAmount; y++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
          var card = {
            value: values[x],
            suit: suits[i],
            status: 'hidden',
            class: 'card',
            id: id,
            'status': 'hidden'
          };
          id++
          deck.push(card);
        }
      }
    }

    return deck;
  }


  function shuffleDeck(array) {

    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }

    return array;

  }

  function divideCardsInColumns(cards) {
    $(cards).slice(0, 6).each(function(index) {
      column1.push(this);
    });
    $(cards).slice(6, 12).each(function(index) {
      column2.push(this);
    });
    $(cards).slice(12, 18).each(function(index) {
      column3.push(this);
    });
    $(cards).slice(18, 24).each(function(index) {
      column4.push(this);
    });
    $(cards).slice(24, 29).each(function(index) {
      column5.push(this);
    });
    $(cards).slice(29, 34).each(function(index) {
      column6.push(this);
    });
    $(cards).slice(34, 39).each(function(index) {
      column7.push(this);
    });
    $(cards).slice(39, 44).each(function(index) {
      column8.push(this);
    });
    $(cards).slice(44, 49).each(function(index) {
      column9.push(this);
    });
    $(cards).slice(49, 54).each(function(index) {
      column10.push(this);
    });
  }

  function appendCardsToColumns() {
    var columns = [];
    columns.push(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8, column9, column10);
    $(columns).each(function(index) {
      var column = $(".column")[index];

      var numberOfCardsInColumn = this.length;

      $(this).each(function(index) {

        $('<div id="' + this.id + '" class="' + this.class + '" data-value="' + this.value + '" data-suit="' + this.suit + '" data-status="' + this.status + '">' + this.value + " of " + this.suit + '<div/>').appendTo($(".down", column)).disableSelection();

        // Get last card in column
        var lastCard = index == numberOfCardsInColumn - 1;

        // Make last card in column draggable and open after it has been appended
        if (lastCard) {
          makeUpDeck($(column));
        }
      });
    });

    initializeDragAndDrop();

    function initializeDragAndDrop() {

      // Make open cards droppable and only accept a cards with a value one less than itself
      var up = $(".card[data-status='open']").closest(".up");

      /*
      if (up.children().length > 1) {
        $(".card[data-status='open']").draggable({
          start: function(event, ui) {
            var allZIindex = [];
            $('.card').each(function() {
              if ($(this)[0].style.zIndex == null) {
                $(this)[0].style.zIndex = 1;
              }
              allZIindex.push($(this)[0].style.zIndex);
            });
            var highestZIndex = Math.max.apply(Math, allZIindex);
            $(this)[0].style.zIndex = highestZIndex + 1;
            var thisAndAllNextCards = $(this).nextAll().addBack();
            if (thisAndAllNextCards.length > 1) {
              $(thisAndAllNextCards).each(function() {
                if ($(this).data("value") == $(this).next('.card').data("value") + 1 && $(this).data("suit") == $(this).next('.card').data("suit")) {
                  $(this).nextAll().addBack().wrapAll("<div class='cardGroup'/>");
                  // All the cards in the variable thisAndAllNextCards (i.e. all the cards in div with class 'cardGroup') should be dragged as a group and appended to the droppable when dropped
                }
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
      */
    }

    /*
    $(".card").on("drop", function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).prev().attr("data-status", "open");
      $(ui.draggable).prev().draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
      });
      $(ui.draggable).insertAfter('#' + $(this).attr("id"));
      $(ui.draggable).css('top', '').css('left', '');
      initializeDragAndDrop();
    });
    */
  }
});
```

```css
.some-page-wrapper {
  margin: 15px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  /*border: 1px solid;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.column .down {}

.column .up {
  margin-top: -10vw;
}

.card[data-status='hidden'] {
  background-color: DarkGray;
  color: DarkGray;
}

.card {
  background-color: LightGray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  font-size: 1vw;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: calc(8vw * 1.4);
  width: 8vw;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10vw;
}

.column .card:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='some-page-wrapper'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='column' id='column1'>
      <div class="down">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column' id='column2'>
      <div class="down">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column' id='column3'>
      <div class="down">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column' id='column4'>
      <div class="down">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column' id='column5'>
      <div class="down">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column' id='column6'>
      <div class="down">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column' id='column7'>
      <div class="down">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column' id='column8'>
      <div class="down">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column' id='column9'>
      <div class="down">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column' id='column10'>
      <div class="down">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With more helper functions, you can do a lot very easily. I went with the `down` and `up` deck containers. This example does not fix or finish out the issue of an empty column, but that can be set pretty easily.

All columns start with a down deck and no up deck. During init, the top card is "flipped" and can be dragged to other decks. That up deck is then appended to. To move the whole deck, the last card can be dragged as a handle. Since you may also need to set the top card to drag, it will need special conditions.

Also be aware that a User can right-click and inspect the cards. They can then see the data attributes. You might consider not using `attr()` but using `data()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time out to help me! I have to go through your code more thoroughly and try to understand what it's doing, but when playing the game I noticed that some rules of Solitaire were missing. I hope they won't ruin your idea, because I like it! 1. When a game starts, all the cards lies in a pile at the top and get dealt (animated) to the columns. 2. When a card is dragged from a column A and dropped onto column B, the last card in column A should flip over and be draggable.

Comment: 3. The most important rule, and the open I'm struggling with: when all the flipped cards after a given flipped card is in a descending straight flush, **all** these card should be draggable. When they are dragged, they should carry with them the cards  after it. In my attached example image, the 5 of clubs should be draggable and carry with it 4, 3 and 2 of clubs. The 4 of clubs should also be draggable and carry with it 3 and 2 of clubs. The 3 of clubs should also be draggable and carry with it 2 of clubs. And so on... :)

Comment: @Allan_Slade there are a number of ways to go about this and not always very easy. A) Make each card in the deck draggable and have them "carry" items above that card. E.G.: 5 < 4 < 3... B) Make a Helper that is a representation of all the cards being carried. Take a look at helper option: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper

Comment: Thanks! I've seen the helper option before but I don't understand the documentation. What will the result be if my draggable is element A and my helper returns element B?

Comment: I finally found an explanation of the helper option that I think I understand: http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-ui/draggable-options-helper.html. The helper is just a visual so I don't think that's a good solution. Right now I'm trying to group descending straight flushes with jQuery's mousedown event.

Comment: @Allan_Slade yes the documentation is a bit spotty yet it's more than just a visual. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923167/draggable-change-html-of-helper/39926521#39926521